# Make recv() block until server recieves user input

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I'm a C & sockets newbie.
I have written a simple ftp server and client in C. Initially it worked, however when I added an option to pwd, it broke. Instead of the server waiting for keyboard input, it runs on the scenario that there is no input. I am using the default settings so it should block. Also, I've added MSG_WAITALL to my recv(), but there is no change. What am i doing wrong?

Relevant server code follows(this is the part that generates a file list for the client and then waits for a filename to transfer via input on the client side).

```
            //wait for ls command
        if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buf, MAXDATASIZE - 1, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        //remove newline from fgets
        strip_newline(buf, sizeof(buf));
        int result = strncmp(cmd, buf, 2);

        if (result == 0){
            //list files
            file = fopen ("temp", "wb");    //we store our file listing in this temp file
            char cmd_buffer[LENGTH];
            dp = opendir ("./");
            if (dp != NULL){
                while (ep = readdir (dp))
                    fprintf(file, "%s\n", ep->d_name);
                (void) closedir (dp);
            }else
                perror ("Couldn't open the directory");   

            //send our list down the wire
            fclose(file);
            file = fopen ("temp", "rb");
            bzero(buffer, LENGTH);
            while ((res = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), LENGTH, file)) > 0){
                if(send(new_fd, buffer, res, 0) < 0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to send file %s. (errno = %d)\n", buf, errno);
                    break;
                }
                bzero(buffer, LENGTH);
            }
            fclose(file);

            //read filename
            if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buf, MAXDATASIZE - 1, MSG_WAITALL)) == -1) {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }
            //remove newline from fgets
            strip_newline(buf, sizeof(buf));
            printf("Trying to open %s\n", buf);
```

Comment: You can not assume recv()/read() and send()/write() do always read/write the amount of data they were told to. You need to loop around such calls until all data is read/written. Please read the relevant man-pages closely.

Comment: @alk Is it possible to make the client keep sending those bytes until it works?

Comment: It's all in the man-pages. The code you show is too much, the problems you seem to be facing are to broad. Boil this down to a particular problem, providing a SSCCE. For what the latter is please read here: http://SSCCE.org

Comment: Also, in `res = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));` you should send `strlen(buffer)+1` to send last `'\0'` character, esp. when you are using it as string without sending length.